# Google Sheets, Live Countdown but with years, months, weeks and days

Tags: google-sheets

I am having trouble trying to find a formula that can give me a count down only showing the years, month, weeks and days.

Like I want it to do this:

1. A1 I type a due date, THEN it shows "(number) Year : (number) Month : (number) Week : (number) Day". The IF the number is greater than 1 THEN "Years : Months : Weeks : Days.
2. IF A1 is greater and equal to B1 THEN show "Over Due!".

Example I type 24 Dec 2023 as a due date, THEN " 0 Year : 1 Month : 1 Week : 1 Day " THEN if today was 24 Dec 2024 THEN "Over Due!".

Thanks

Comment: don't use months at all and this is much simpler and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the concept of "week" is well defined in this context — it could be any period of seven days, a calendar week from Sunday to Saturday, a calendar week from Monday to Sunday (as it is recognized in most of Europe, Asia and Africa), or something else. Further, most months contain fractions of five calendar weeks, but February may only contain four in some years. It is unclear how one would calculate months vs. fractional weeks vs. full weeks.

To get the duration between the date in cell `A1` and the current date as *years, months and days*, use this pattern:

```
=let( 
  durationText_, lambda(start, end, let(c_,lambda(d,if((d="")+isnumber(d),d,to_date(value(d)))),f_,lambda(t,t-int(t)),map(start,end,lambda(x,y,let(s,c_(x),e,c_(y),d_,lambda(u,datedif(s,e,u)),t_,lambda(u,text(e-s,u)),r,d_("md")-(f_(s)>f_(e)),d,if(r<0,day(eomonth(e,-1))-1,r),m,d_("ym")-(r<0),ifs(not(isnumber(s)*isnumber(e)),,s>=e,"Overdue",true,textjoin(", ",1,map({d_("y")-(m<0),mod(m,12),max(0,d),t_("H"),regexextract(t_("H:m"),":(\d+)"),t_("s")},{"year","month","day","hour","minute","second"},lambda(n,u,switch(n&"","0",,"1",n&" "&u,n&" "&u&"s")))))))))), 

  durationText_(today(), A1) 
)
```

To get the difference for all dates in columns `B1:B` and `A1:A` in one go, use this:

```
=let( 
  durationText_, lambda(start, end, let(c_,lambda(d,if((d="")+isnumber(d),d,to_date(value(d)))),f_,lambda(t,t-int(t)),map(start,end,lambda(x,y,let(s,c_(x),e,c_(y),d_,lambda(u,datedif(s,e,u)),t_,lambda(u,text(e-s,u)),r,d_("md")-(f_(s)>f_(e)),d,if(r<0,day(eomonth(e,-1))-1,r),m,d_("ym")-(r<0),ifs(not(isnumber(s)*isnumber(e)),,s>=e,"Overdue",true,textjoin(", ",1,map({d_("y")-(m<0),mod(m,12),max(0,d),t_("H"),regexextract(t_("H:m"),":(\d+)"),t_("s")},{"year","month","day","hour","minute","second"},lambda(n,u,switch(n&"","0",,"1",n&" "&u,n&" "&u&"s")))))))))), 

  durationText_(B1:B, A1:A) 
)
```

Put the formula in row 1 of a free column.